# How to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'mshtml.HTMLElementCollection

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, mshtml

I am trying to use mshtml to fill a form on vb.net through the webbrowser control,

```
Dim doc As MSH.IHTMLDocument2 = DirectCast(wbMain.Document.DomDocument, MSH.IHTMLDocument2)
Dim buttons As MSH.HTMLElementCollection = doc.getElementsByTagName("button")
Dim Inputs As MSH.HTMLElementCollection = doc.getElementsByTagName("input")
```

but I get the following error:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
> type 'mshtml.HTMLElementCollection'. This operation failed because the
> QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID
> '{3050F56B-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B}' failed due to the following
> error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002
> (E_NOINTERFACE)).

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Dim buttons As MSH.HTMLElementCollection

Wrong type.  That should be an IHTMLElementCollection instead.  Note the leading I.  The MSDN page [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa703989%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

The type that is missing the I is a coclass, not an interface.  Used by scripting clients when they want to create their own collection object.