# VBA RunTime Error 13: Type mismatch - HTMLElementCollection

Tags: html, vba, variables

I am trying to loop through all table elements on a page, but am getting the above noted error. Here is my code:

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim ieDOC As HTMLDocument
Dim tableElements As HTMLElementCollection
Dim tableElement As HTMLTable

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
eURL = "url_of_site_to_visit"
ie.navigate ieURL
Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop
Set ieDOC = ie.Document
Set tableElements = ieDoc.getElementsByTagName("table")
```

For some reason, I am getting "Type mismatch" on the `Set tableElements = ieDoc.getElementsByTagName("table")` line of code.

Also, when debugging, it tells me `tableElements = Nothing`

I have added references to "Microsoft HTML Object Library" and "Microsoft Internet Controls".

Any direction as to what is causing, or how to fix, the error would be appreciated.

Comment: errrrg... Still no clue as to the cause of the error...

Answer (score 1):

Think it should be `IHTMLElementCollection` (note the `I` at the beginning) because that's the type of object which `getElementsByTagName` returns

Comment: i just ran into the same problem and found the same solution. but it leaves me unsatisfied. what is the purpose of the type `HTMLElementCollection`, which intellisense also knows?

Comment: found kind of an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210584/unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-system-comobject-to-interface-type-mshtml